# OO Design Issue with IDs

Tags: java, oop

Say as an example I have a Player class that has a race via a Race class. These races are fixed in number and are loaded into an array which can be accessed statically.

My question is whether the Player class should have an index ID number which would then need to call the static function getRaceByID(int) to retrieve the Race class to do some internal calculations. Now I could get around having to do this if I was to have the race reference directly in the Player class, but then saving the player to a file becomes problematic. I only want a reference to the Race be stored along with the Player data. Like an ID.

I want to avoid storing a copy of the Race data and instead just reference it. Is there anything I should be doing differently? Are there any patterns to address something like this? Databases deal with IDs, but it doesn't seem to work very well in OO development. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
class Player
{
  Race race;
}
```

In this case I would need to compare this race to the races in my static array so that I can properly write out the index ID. Another solution is to store the ID in the Race class itself so that I can reference it directly from the Race class like so:

`race.getID();`

Or would it be better to go with something like this to enforce this relationship:

`class Player
{
  int raceID;
}`

Race r = MyFile.getRaceByID(raceID);

// can now use race

Comment: Please specify the language you're using

Comment: and what's your persistence mechanism? Standard binary serialization?

Comment: Java, and outputing via an INIWriter I've written.

Comment: Tell, Don't Ask. http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's no reason that your ID based concept won't work. It doesn't violate any OO principles, and has several benefits. I see no reason NOT to go that route, especially if you've already determined that it would work well for you.

As an aside, if you want to avoid having `static_races[player.race_id]` scattered throughout your code, a simple wrapper function would suffice in maintaining a more "OO feel" (Psudocode, since you haven't stated a language:

```
function Race Player::GetRace() {
    return static_races[this.race_id];
}
```

Simple, but effective. No need to over complicate things.

Comment: That's exactly how I do it right now. But I do have the GetRace function in a different file so that any class could call it to pull the race. Though it might be better to go with that idea and put it in the classes that need it. I think that would work really well. Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious: Why the downvote? It's a valid answer, and one that the QA is apparently happy with. If you have a reason (hopefully more than "that's not how I would do it") why this is not a desirable solution, please explain why in the comments. Simply downvoting an answer without explanation isn't beneficial to anyone. (You're free to disagree with me, of course. Just talk about why, please!)

Answer (score 1):

What you have in memory does not have to be what you store in a database.

The details will depend upon the language you're using and the Object-to-Database technology.

If you have

```
Player {
     Race myRace;
     // etc
}
```

This does not necesserily imply that you have a *copy* of the Race, in some languages this would imply a "reference" or "pointer" to a Race.

When you come to store in the database it would be quite normal for just the Id of the race to be stored.

In other words, you don't need to compromise the OO design to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: I understand that it would be a reference, but the problem is getting that ID then. In this case, I would have to do a lookup through N number of races to find which one it was to successfully write it out to a file. I guess I could store the ID in the Race class as well, but there's not any safeguard mechanisms to prevent say assigning an invalid race to the Player. Doing it the previous way is more messy, but forces this relationship.

Comment: Races would have an ID, there would be a foreign key relationship in the database, Person's ID field matching the primary key ID in the Race, ORM tools manage this for you. The management of such many to one realtionships is all pretty standard, it doesn't turn out to be a big deal in the C# and Java worlds. Have a look at how something such as Hibernate works.

Answer (score 0):

Of some relevance to using IDs in an OO design: *[Modern C++ Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315)* by Alexandrescu has an excellent chapter on object factories. If you have a big switch statement on your ID, then you could probably benefit from reading this chapter, as it will show you the OO way to handle that sort of thing. As the book says:

> The Shape-Drawing example [of
>   polymorphism] is often
>   encountered in C++ books, including
>   Bjarne Stroustrup's classic
>   (Stroustrup 1997). However, most
>   introductory C++ books stop when it
>   comes to loading graphics from a file,
>   exactly because the nice model of
>   having separate drawing objects
>   breaks.... A straightforward implementation
>   is to require each Shape-derived
>   object to save an integral identifier
>   at the very beginning. Each object
>   should have its own unique ID. Then
>   reading a file would look like this:
>
> [code with big switch]
>
> .... The only
>   problem [with this type of code] is that it
>   breaks the most important rules of
>   object orientation: [E.G.,] It
>   collects in a single source file
>   knowledge about all Shape-derived
>   classes in the program....